# Does the zero sequence $(0, 0, ...)$ have "finite support"?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was working through a proof recently where I was considering the intersection of:

1. The set $\operatorname {span} \{(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, ...)\}$
2. the set of sequences with finite support, i.e., finitely many nonzero elements

I was wondering, would this intersection be $\emptyset$? or would it be $\{0\}$?

Comment: Yes, the zero sequence has finite support. Personally, I have no idea what "the intersection of the span of an everywhere-nonzero basis vector" and "the intersection of the set of sequences with finite support" are supposed to mean.

Comment: i'll edit to clarify

Comment: Be careful with how you use your braces `{}` .

Comment: Remember that the intersection of any two subspaces is a subspace. With this in mind, is it possible for the intersection of these two subspaces to be empty?

Comment: The empty set is finite.

Comment: @K.defaoite thank you for the formatting edits! No idea why my latex wasn't working.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor ah! ok, thanks. so the set of sequences with finitely many nonzero elements is a subspace? i honestly wasn't sure. that answers my question. i just wasn't sure.

Comment: @william_grisaitis When putting things inside braces for formatting, such as text for example, use them as normal, e.g `\text{hello}` outputs $\text{hello}$. When you want to just have braces printed, use a backslash, e.g `\{1,2,3,\dots\}`  prints $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$